React Native: Android: Task 'testClasses' not found in project ':ffmpeg-kit-react-native'
I've updated React Native version from 0.70 to 0.72,
Also I've updated the dependencies and now getting this error,
Task 'testClasses' not found in project ':ffmpeg-kit-react-native'.
"ffmpeg-kit-react-native": "^6.0.2",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.72.0",

Try:


Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

Error Image
